# I need a formula or macro to sum a row of mixed data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a column of data like this:

```
Cage
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
Cage
1
1
1
1
Cage
1
1
1
1
1
```

What I need is another column next to it to say something like.

```
Cage
7
Cage
4
Cage
5
```

The problem is the information changes every day, and the input cannot be altered. The 1's are the contents of the cage. The next day it may be:

```
Cage 
1
Cage
1
1
Cage
1
1
1
```

Comment: Is it always 3 cages?

Comment: No, the amount of cages and the amount of items in the cages change every day.

Comment: Is that edit accurate? It's not what I was seeing in my head, although it makes sense.

Comment: Yea, Cage is A1 1 is A2 1 is A3, so on. I need B1 to say Cage again, B2 to sum A2-A7. B3 to Say Cage, B4 to sum A4-A7, and so on. I just can't figure out how to get it to do this with changing information in A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a procedure that calculates this:

```
Public Sub SumCages()
Dim current_row, summary_row, item_total As Integer

current_row = 1
While Sheet1.Cells(current_row, 1) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet1.Cells(current_row, 1)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet1.Cells(current_row, 1))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet1.Cells(summary_row, 2) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet1.Cells(summary_row, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(current_row, 1) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet1.Cells(summary_row + 1, 2) = item_total

End Sub
```

[image]

Your data has to conform to the question specifics:

- Have a non-numeric entry as a label;
- Numeric entries below each label (could be different from 1).

---

Specific to the document posted, the following produces the expected output:

```
Public Sub SumCages()
Dim current_row, summary_row, item_total As Integer

current_row = 45
summary_row = 44
While Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19) <> ""
  If IsNumeric(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19)) Then
    item_total = item_total + Val(Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19))
  Else
    summary_row = summary_row + 1 ' Advance summary_row
    If item_total > 0 Then
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 20) = item_total ' Display total
      current_row = current_row - 1 ' Correct advancement
    Else
      Sheet8.Cells(summary_row, 20) = Sheet8.Cells(current_row, 19) ' Copy label
    End If
    item_total = 0 ' Reset item_total
  End If
  current_row = current_row + 1 ' Advance current_row
Wend
Sheet8.Cells(summary_row + 1, 20) = item_total

End Sub
```

Comment: The top half (above black line) is irrelevant. Below the black line is where I'm having issues.

Comment: @user2727453: You need to understand the basics of cell references for VBA. `Sheet8` refers to `Data`, and a reference like `Sheet8.Cells(<row>,<col>)` refers to the cell contents in row `<row>` and column `<col>` on `Sheet8`.

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you for your help. I know nothing about VBA and only a little basic excel. Can this be applied to every "C" Column?

Comment: @user2727453: You can sequentially change column `19` and `20` to whatever the "input" and "output" columns are.